# What is this ArgumentOutOfRangeException caused by?

Tags: c#, list, indexing, argumentexception

I have a problem that drives me nuts. I am using a generic List that throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException whenever I try to assign its first (or last?) index to a variable. It's a pretty large pile of code, hence I'll try to extract only the relevant stuff. So here it is:

```
private string GetRuleByName(string name, List<string> rules)
{
    if(rules != null)
    {
        List<string> todo = new List<string>();
        todo.AddRange(rules);

        while(rules.Count != 0)
        {
            string r = todo[0]; // <- Error 'ArgumentOutOfRangeException' here
            todo.RemoveAt(0);

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

That's how I call the method:

```
void treeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    string currentRule = GetRuleByName(treeView.SelectedNode.FullPath, ruleCollection)
    // the string list "ruleCollection" always contains
    // strings and thus is never empty
}
```

Even though it's not a very detailed presentation of what's going on, as I had to cut off a piece of some complicated code, I really hope someone else might see what produces the error.

Big thanks in advance for at least having a look!

**EDIT**:

This is how the method looks like. I haven't altered anything, to show what's really inside it. I hope it makes sense for somebody:

```
private Rule GetRuleByNameOrId(string stName, List<Rule> rules)
{
    if(rules != null)
    {
        string searchName = stName.ToLower().Trim();
        string subName = "";
        int slashPos = searchName.IndexOf('/');

        if(slashPos != -1)
        {
            if(slashPos != searchName.Length)
                subName = searchName.Substring(slashPos + 1);
            searchName = searchName.Substring(0, slashPos);
        }

        List<Rule> todo = new List<Rule>();
        todo.AddRange(rules);

        while(todo.Count != 0)
        {
            Rule r = (Rule)todo[0];
            todo.RemoveAt(0);

            if(r.Name.ToLower() == searchName || r.Id.ToLower() == searchName)
            {
                if(subName != "")
                {
                    Rule subRule = GetRuleByNameOrId(subName, r.Children);

                    if(subRule != null)
                        return subRule;
                }
                else
                {
                    return r;
                }
            }
            if(r.Children != null && r.Children.Count != 0)
                todo.AddRange(r.Children);
        }//end while
    }//end if(rules != null)
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You loop while `rules.Count != 0` but you remove items from todo using `todo.RemoveAt(0)` - therefore you run out of items in todo and the index goes out of range because `rules.Count` is always > 0. Did you mean to do `while(todo.Count != 0)` instead?

Comment: `todo` is an empty list - it has no 0th element

Comment: `todo` isn't empty Preston - there's an `todo.AddRange` call before the loop and since the OP says that `rules` is never empty, we have to look at the code to see where the indexing of `todo` could be out of range

Comment: Could you explain the logic of item removal from the todo list? A part from the trivial loop error probably there are better ways to prepare the todo list knowing the logic required. As is and without knowing the omitted code your todo list will be totally empty at the end of the loop so why adding elements there in the first place?

Comment: @Steve I know it is impossible to see what's going on. As I stated in my question, it is not easy to make a meaningful cut, as the code is very complex. But nevertheless I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want the following:

```
private string GetRuleByName(string name, List<string> rules)
{
    if(rules != null)
    {
        List<string> todo = new List<string>();
        todo.AddRange(rules);

        while(todo.Count != 0) // <-- Minor mod here
        {
            string r = todo[0]; 
            todo.RemoveAt(0);

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you are infinitely looping on `rules.Count` as the size of `rules` is not changing

This works fine until `todo` is empty, then you get the exception because element 0 no longer exists as you've removed them all!

Comment: Thanks! That gets rid of the ArgumentException. Just one more question though. Could you please have a look at the original method that I added to my question and tell me if your modification fits the original context? Because now a NullReferenceException is thrown three lines below at the line if(r.Name.ToLower()...) and I'm not sure if this is because I'm checking for the todo.Count now.

Comment: Can't see any good reason for a null ref. The only things that it could be are: `Name` is null on one of the `Rule` instances or the `r.Children` collection contains a null reference in one of the rules (or in the original rules list). Have you tried debugging - or is there any reason you haven't tried debugging?

Comment: Yes I tried and finally succeeded. `r.Name` was indeed null. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't want this instead:

```
while(rules.Count != 0)
{
    string r = rules[0]; // <- Error 'ArgumentOutOfRangeException' here
    rules.RemoveAt(0);
```

?

The way you've written it now, you've got a loop that would actually be infinite, except that you eventually remove all the elements from the `todo` list, at which point you throw the exception (because in an empty list even the 0-th element doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but two seperated lists are required for the code to work. I know you weren't supposed to know that. Just telling.

Comment: Just telling what? I don't even know what the thing you wrote means. The bottom line here is that you can't go around removing elements from one list but use the count of a different list to decide you're done. Maybe you want `todo` everywhere instead of `rules` everywhere, but one way or the other you have to stick with the same list instead of mixing the two. _That's_ the salient part.

Comment: Point taken. I updated my question. I'm not sure, but may be now it makes a little bit more sense to you, or rather not. It's the original method that includes also variables that are declared somewhere else in the code.